# How to call IActionResult from Javascript?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an ASP.NET Application and want to call this `IActionResult` method from the `HomeController`:

```
public IActionResult ReadNewestFile(FileInfo filePath) {
    String st = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(filePath.ToString());

    ChartData chartData = new ChartData();
    string[] lines = st.Split("\n");

    foreach (var line in lines) {
        string[] values = line.Split(',');
        try {
            chartData = new ChartData {
                Timestamp = Convert.ToDateTime(values[0] + "." + values[1]),
                Function = Convert.ToString(values[2]),
                Duration = Convert.ToInt32(values[4]),
                IsError = Convert.ToBoolean(values[5])
            };
            db.ChartDatas.Add(chartData);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception exc) {
            exc.ToString();
        }
    }
    return View(chartData);
}
```

Now I want to get the return value of this method in the `site.js` file:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "Home/ReadNewestFile",
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

When I try it like this, the browser says "500 Internal Error". Any ideas to solve this problem?

Comment: You missing parameter "filePath". My suggestion to change parameter from FileInfo type to string. And send it with your request

Comment: Do you want to render the view via js code? Or just get the `chartData` as a json object and then work with that json object via js code?

Comment: @Izzy I want to get the Chart Data as a JSON-Object and work with it in the code

Comment: Change return `View(chatData)` to return `Json(chartData)`